# App flashes the previous state randomly in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, crash

I am facing a weird problem that at times, if the app crashes and when I restart the app it flashes the previous state of the app and then the splash screen open. How do I fix this weird problem or is it possible to fix it.

Comment: Seems reallly straightforward: fix the crash.

Comment: Have you set the launch image?\

Comment: Are you using the restorationID for the `UIViewController` on which the app crashes? iOS is trying to restore your previous state.

Comment: @Eric Qian: Yes. Whats next :)?

Comment: @danialzahid94: No,not anywhere.